# Screen flickering on HP Victus Windows 11

Tags: google-chrome, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, amd-ryzen, hardware-acceleration

I recently purchased a new [HP Victus laptop](https://www.hp.com/in-en/shop/victus-gaming-laptop-15-fb0051ax-6f9t9pa.html) and every time I used Chrome or Edge, the screen would flicker. This issue isn't happening on any other apps or any other browser like Firefox.
[image]

I then came across [this troubleshooting article](https://www.guidingtech.com/top-ways-to-fix-google-chrome-screen-flickering-in-windows-11/) and turned off hardware acceleration. This stopped the screen from flickering on both Edge and Chrome. This made sense because Edge and Chrome are based on Chromium and Firefox isn't, so the issue is browser-specific.

While the above worked, I was not satisfied.

On Edge, I turned hardware acceleration back on and reproduced the issue. Then from [the troubleshooting article](https://www.guidingtech.com/top-ways-to-fix-google-chrome-screen-flickering-in-windows-11/) linked above, I set the graphics preference for Edge. I manually added Edge to the list and then from the options, I tried AMD but that didn't stop the flickering. Then I selected NVIDIA and that resolved the issue.
[image]

In summary, these two fixes worked -

- Chrome, turned hardware acceleration system setting to off, no
  explicit graphics preference set.
- Edge, turned hardware acceleration
  system setting to on, and explicitly set graphics preference to
  NVIDIA.

While the above two fixes works, I don't understand technically what was wrong and what the above fixes did under the hood. Could I pls get some help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the two browsers have problems adapting to your (too?)
modern hardware ...

All I can do is guess :

Chrome looks like it was trying with hardware acceleration to use
super-efficiently directly the GPU, which it did very badly.
Once this was turned off, it used the system GPU through Windows API,
which worked better.

Edge looked like it was also having problems with a laptop that doesn't
have Integrated Graphics. But once it knew which GPU to use, performance
has improved.

The basic problem is the same - your particular hardware.
The solutions may differ because of the different graphical implementation
in each browser.

Comment: I see! So this is kinda the only solution to the problem, isn't it? I mean it isn't a hardware issue specifically otherwise something else could break. Probably just need to raise an issue with Chrome so it catches up to the modern hardware?

Comment: You may do so. I think that you have empirically arrived at a good workaround that has no negative aspects and no performance issues.